# JS no detecta cuando un elemento es borrado

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando que este script JS detecte cuando el formulario es borrado. El problema es que se detecta que el elemento padre cambia, pero no cuando es eliminado el form (hijo).

Las comprobaciones no funcionan y ya probé muchísimas cosas.

El formulario (todo el html) es generado por un plugin Bloom de Wordpress, el problema es que es muy poco personalizable y tengo que usarlo sí o sí.

Gracias!

```
var form = document.getElementsByClassName('et_bloom_form_content et_bloom_2_fields et_bloom_bottom_stacked')[0];
form.addEventListener("change", function() {
  if (form.getElementsByTagName('form')[0] === undefined) {
    dataLayer.push({'event': 'form1_empresas'});
    console.log('enviado0');
  }
});
```

El elemento padre junto al form (hijo) es el siguiente:

```
<div class="et_bloom_form_content et_bloom_2_fields et_bloom_bottom_stacked">
  <form method="post" class="clearfix"><p class="et_bloom_popup_input et_bloom_subscribe_name">
    <input placeholder="Tu nombre" maxlength="50"></p><p class="et_bloom_popup_input et_bloom_subscribe_email">
    <input placeholder="Email"></p>
    <button data-optin_id="optin_4" data-service="activecampaign" data-list_id="21" data-page_id="11601" data-account="Chile" data-disable_dbl_optin="" class="et_bloom_submit_subscription">
      <span class="et_bloom_subscribe_loader"></span>
      <span class="et_bloom_button_text et_bloom_button_text_color_light">ENVIAR</span>
      </button>
  </form>
  <div class="et_bloom_success_container"> 
    <span class="et_bloom_success_checkmark"></span>
    </div>
  <h2 class="et_bloom_success_message">Recibimos tu correo correctamente, te estaremos contactando en breve.</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: podrias agregar tu html ? asi nos permites ayudarte de la mejor manera

Comment: @Federico ahí lo actualicé en el cuerpo del mensaje!

Comment: no entiendo que quieres hacer.... y porque se elimina el form? fuerda de que change es un listener que espera una accion de cambio por parte del usuario y el change se ejecuta al momento de que el usuario empieza a escribir en el form y aun sigue existiendo, si lo eliminas al change el usuario no podra escribir remplantea tu logica o explicate mejor!

Comment: Una vez que el formulario es enviado (y validado), se elimina el form, y se muestra el mensaje de que los datos fueron enviados. El plugin elimina el form. La idea es que mi script detecte que el form fue eliminado

Answer (score 0):

Intenta lo siguiente:
cuando se le de al botón de enviar, en tu caso `<span class="et_bloom_button_text et_bloom_button_text_color_light">ENVIAR</span>`, intentale darle un evento que escuche `click`. Para eso dale una id al form y al botón. Quedaria algo asi:

```js
document.getElementById("enviarForm").addEventListener("click", function(){
  if(document.getElementById("formulario") == null){
    //el formulario no existe, todo se ha enviado correctamente
  }else{
    //el formulario existe, ha fallado algo
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="et_bloom_form_content et_bloom_2_fields et_bloom_bottom_stacked">
  <form method="post" class="clearfix" id="formulario">
    <p class="et_bloom_popup_input et_bloom_subscribe_name">
    <input placeholder="Tu nombre" maxlength="50"></p><p class="et_bloom_popup_input et_bloom_subscribe_email">
    <input placeholder="Email"></p>
    <button data-optin_id="optin_4" data-service="activecampaign" data-list_id="21" data-page_id="11601" data-account="Chile" data-disable_dbl_optin="" class="et_bloom_submit_subscription">
      <span class="et_bloom_subscribe_loader"></span>
      <span class="et_bloom_button_text et_bloom_button_text_color_light" id="enviarForm">ENVIAR</span>
      </button>
  </form>
  <div class="et_bloom_success_container"> 
    <span class="et_bloom_success_checkmark"></span>
    </div>
  <h2 class="et_bloom_success_message">Recibimos tu correo correctamente, te estaremos contactando en breve.</h2>
</div>
```

Espero que te sirva

Answer (score 0):

te aconsejaria utilizar el `MutationObserver`, que sirve para observar los cambiamentos que hay en el DOM. en [este link en ingles](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) podes ver la documentacion sobre este metodo para tener mas informaciones.

En el caso que pasaste, no te detecta que el `form` es eliminado por el simple echo que no es un cambio lo que afecta al formulario, la eliminacion del mismo afecta la estructura del DOM.

aca te dejo un ejemplo del utilizo del `MutationObserver` :

```js
var target = document.getElementsByClassName('et_bloom_form_content et_bloom_2_fields et_bloom_bottom_stacked')[0];
var boton = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];

var node = document.createElement("H2");                 
var textnode = document.createTextNode("Recibimos tu correo correctamente, te estaremos contactando en breve.");
node.className = "et_bloom_success_message";
node.appendChild(textnode);

var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
        if (mutation.removedNodes.length > 0) {
           target.appendChild(node);
           console.log("enviado");
        }
           
    });
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    characterData: true
};

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

boton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    this.parentNode.remove();
})
```

```html
<div class="et_bloom_form_content et_bloom_2_fields et_bloom_bottom_stacked">
  <form method="post" class="clearfix" id="formulario">
    <p class="et_bloom_popup_input et_bloom_subscribe_name">
    <input placeholder="Tu nombre" maxlength="50"></p><p class="et_bloom_popup_input et_bloom_subscribe_email">
    <input placeholder="Email"></p>
    <button data-optin_id="optin_4" data-service="activecampaign" data-list_id="21" data-page_id="11601" data-account="Chile" data-disable_dbl_optin="" class="et_bloom_submit_subscription">
      <span class="et_bloom_subscribe_loader"></span>
      <span class="et_bloom_button_text et_bloom_button_text_color_light" id="enviarForm">ENVIAR</span>
      </button>
  </form>
  <div class="et_bloom_success_container"> 
    <span class="et_bloom_success_checkmark"></span>
    </div>
  
</div>
```

en caso contratio prueba usando `DOMSubtreeModified` en vez de `change`, para detectar el cambiamento del DOM al interno del elemento padre.

> **ATENCION!** este tipo de evento esta deprecado

```js
var form = document.getElementsByClassName('et_bloom_form_content et_bloom_2_fields et_bloom_bottom_stacked')[0];
form.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
  if (form.getElementsByTagName('form')[0] === undefined) {
    //dataLayer.push({'event': 'form1_empresas'});
    console.log('enviado0');
  }
});

var boton = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];

boton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    this.parentNode.remove();
})
```

```html
<div class="et_bloom_form_content et_bloom_2_fields et_bloom_bottom_stacked">
  <form method="post" class="clearfix"><p class="et_bloom_popup_input et_bloom_subscribe_name">
    <input placeholder="Tu nombre" maxlength="50"></p><p class="et_bloom_popup_input et_bloom_subscribe_email">
    <input placeholder="Email"></p>
    <button>
      <span class="et_bloom_subscribe_loader"></span>
      <span class="et_bloom_button_text et_bloom_button_text_color_light">ENVIAR</span>
      </button>
  </form>
  <div class="et_bloom_success_container"> 
    <span class="et_bloom_success_checkmark"></span>
    </div>
  <h2 class="et_bloom_success_message">Recibimos tu correo correctamente, te estaremos contactando en breve.</h2>
</div>
```

visto que el `DOMSubtreeModified` esta deprecado en algunos browsers no funciona, por lo personal hice un test y en chrome que firefox todavia funciona. (tene presente que igualmente puede dejar de funcionar en las prosimas actualizcaiones).

espero que te sea de ayuda, exitos !